# Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I created an starter project from spring tool suite with config shown below
[image: Boot App]

when I run the App with changing of

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class FirstApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FirstApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/greet")
    public String helloGreeting() {
        return "Salam REST";
    }
}
```

it crashes saying

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.6.RELEASE)

2015-10-03 08:18:45.362  INFO 4100 --- [           main] c.rhcloud.arshad.demo.FirstApplication   : Starting FirstApplication on Arshad with PID 4100 (F:\Boot-work\first\target\classes started by Arshay in F:\Boot-work\first)
2015-10-03 08:18:45.487  INFO 4100 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@11f23e5: startup date [Sat Oct 03 08:18:45 PKT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-10-03 08:18:46.732  INFO 4100 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-10-03 08:18:48.387  WARN 4100 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
    at com.rhcloud.arshad.demo.FirstApplication.main(FirstApplication.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:331)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3073)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3050)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addDefaultServlet(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 common frames omitted

2015-10-03 08:18:48.391  INFO 4100 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/F:/Boot-work/first/target/classes/, file:/F:/Boot-work/first/target/test-classes/, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.12/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.26/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.26/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.26.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.26/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.26.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.26/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.26.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.6/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.6/jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.6/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.2.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-test-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/mockito-core-1.10.19.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Arshay/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-test-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar]
2015-10-03 08:18:48.393 ERROR 4100 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
    at com.rhcloud.arshad.demo.FirstApplication.main(FirstApplication.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:331)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3073)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3050)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addDefaultServlet(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
    at com.rhcloud.arshad.demo.FirstApplication.main(FirstApplication.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:331)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.URLDecode(UDecoder.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3073)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3050)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addDefaultServlet(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, that you use a wrong JRE to run this application. Make sure, that you running your it with Java version 1.7 or above, especially if you run it via some IDE. StandardCharsets, due to [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html), is available since version 1.7.

Comment: Are you sure, that your app is running under the same jre as it is build? Try to print the system property java.version just before the running spring boot app in main method, to check this out.

Comment: It says 1.7.0-ea is that ea early access? have you tried a newer 1.7? or perhaps since you specify above to use 1.8 you could change to the 1.8 I see in your eclipse configs?

Comment: Agree with @Zergled, update your jdk or try to use 1.8. It's not a good idea to use early access version, then exist for a long time a stable one